# Posting a message on another person's Twitter wall

Tags: twitter

Is there a way on Twitter to post on someone's wall? Like on Facebook, I could either post directly on his wall or mention a person in my message with the @ sign for the message to show up on his wall or tag the person in a picture.

For Twitter, would mentioning a person with an @ sign post the message on the person's wall too? Otherwise, is there a way to post on a person's Twitter wall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't. You can `@` mention them. The only way for this to appear on their 'wall' (timeline) is if they was to hit 'retweet' on that mention.